# Windows phone silverlight 8 gridview for items

Tags: c#, silverlight, gridview, windows-phone-8, uwp

I am creating an windows phone silverlight 8 app. Which will run on windows 8, 8.1 and 10 phone devices only after publishing to store.

My question is how to create a GridView in it? I already know how to create longlist view and scroll it, in one column, what I want to do is I want same functionality but with 2 columns. Its similar to any gridview on any platform, columns number can be unlimited, by in my case only 2 columns will be good enough. and when I select an item will will invoke item selected or selection changed events, just like normal longlist in silverlight.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually it is an app which needs to target only the phone devices of windows. and all 3 phone device support is needed., i.e: 8, 8.1 and 10. it doesn't need to target Desktop or any other device, only the phone family. so what kind of project do you recommend for this purpose?

Comment: Have you tried HubApp template or PivotApp template?